# Filenet user cache refresh

Tags: active-directory, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, content-platform-engine

When a 'new' user is added to an existing AD group or we create a new AD 'group' we have to wait too long for the cache in P8 to be updated. If I transfer any workflow into the region it will update the cache immediately.

Our java program is creating these new users and groups in the AD. We need a solution when creating a new user or group via a java program that we can call 'something' to refresh the cache in p8 / update the tables in Oracle.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

CE retrieves user and group objects from the Directory Server (DS) based on a particular interval. The User Token Cache Entry Time-To-Live (TTL) value (in seconds) determines the interval which the CE communicates to the configured the DS for user and group schema object updates.

While personally I have not seen such a function, however, theoretically it is possible to do this by setting value programmatically, apply it, and then roll it back (so that you wont suffer performance hit), in the end if the FEM can do it then you can.
Here are the steps to modify this value :

1. Launch FileNet Enterprise Manager ( FEM ) and log on using a
   Directory Service account.
2. In FEM, go to Domain properties-> Server Cache and Change the User Token Cache TTL (seconds) default of 3600s to the desired
   amount.
3. Click OK

[image]

**Note**: This setting could have an negative impact on performance. If large numbers of DS schema objects are updated and the setting is set to a low interval (for example: 360 seconds), performance could be impacted on CE server.

Comment: Pre P8 CPE the service would hunt for a name in the actual directory if not found in cache. NOW however, IBM has removed that functionality and relies solely on a max 4 hour cache refresh. I have place a feature request into IBM after spending a long time on a PMR. I hope they get the need to find new users created on demand. We've extended P8 workflow to the java app for external clients. In business terms we can't expect a business client to wait 4 hours to use an app. 

Vote for the request at : 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=90140

Comment: @rickmac true that, we have had the same issue of the 4 hours cache issue and the PMR guys told us that this is how it works, we ended up resorting to the updating the values through FEM